# gtk entry set_position doesn't move the cursor

Tags: perl, gtk

Why this piece of code doesn't move the cursor to the last character of the entry?

```
use Gtk2 '-init';
my $window = Gtk2::Window->new;
my $entry = Gtk2::Entry->new;

my $handler;
$handler = $entry->signal_connect ( 'insert-text' =>
    sub {
        my (
            $entry,
            $chrs,
            $len,
            $pos_strange,
            $handler,
        ) = @_;
        $entry->signal_handler_block ( $$handler );
        $entry->set_text ( 'tryme' );
        $entry->signal_stop_emission_by_name ('insert-text');
        $entry->signal_handler_unblock ( $$handler );
        $entry->set_position ( -1 );
    },
    \$handler
);

$window->set_size_request ( 200, 100 );
$window->add ( $entry );
$window->set_position ('center_always');
$window->show_all;
$window->signal_connect ( delete_event => sub { Gtk2->main_quit; } );
Gtk2->main;
```

Comment: Maybe Gtk2 is changing the position itself after execution of the handler? To workaround this, you can try to defer setting the position, e.g. using something like `Glib::Idle->add (sub { $entry->set_position ( -1 ) });`

Comment: Another possibility: instead of calling `set_text` yourself and protect from inifinite loops in the signal handling, you can just return `($new_text, $new_position)`. For some reason, "-1" does not seem to work, but the following seems to work: `("tryme", length($entry->get_text . "tryme"))`

Answer (score 3):

When the last `insert-text` handler returns Gtk updates the cursor position using the value of `pos` so your code is moving the cursor and then Gtk is moving it again. You could use an idle callback as suggested above but it would probably be cleaner to update pos in your handler. You want to do the perl equivalent of `*pos = g_utf8_strlen ("tryme"), 0)` instead of `$entry->set_position ( -1 );`